# Connect Oracle Autonomous Database in Microsoft Azure Data Factory

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Anyone in here have already connected Oracle Autonomous DB in Azure Data Factory?

We are trying to implement some data copies from SQL Server to Oracle, but I am not able to reach Oracle Autonomous Database, using standard host, port, service name and credentials.
Maybe any security layer related to the Wallet is missing?
I can't find any documents explaining.

The error when trying to connect is:
ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]Socket closed.
ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]Connection Dead.

Thanks,
Guilherme

Answer (score 2):

You are using a 3rd Party ODBC Driver in sense of Oracle - please have a look here for other issues using the Microsoft ODBC driver

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4537072/fix-creating-an-external-table-against-an-oracle-database-in-sql-serve

I'm not sure if the workaround applying the patch for SQL Server will help - same for setting

sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server=8

on Oracle Server machin - but at least its a better idea to use the Oracle ODBC Driver or OLEDB Provider connecting from SQL Server to Oracle DB (and you got the oppertunity to open Service request at Oracle when not working :-)

placing on Oracle $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin or wherelse sqlnet.ora is stored on database will work

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping me with this. Just moved my question to the appropriate forum: https://serverfault.com/questions/1037106/connect-oracle-autonomous-database-in-microsoft-azure-data-factory